# not making bar button items and title on nav bar (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

On my main navigationController, there is a right bar button called `"Next Page"`. When the button is pressed, it calls the method called `"nextPage()"` which initializes the navigation controller and show it.

The code for `nextPage()` is like following:

```
func nextPage() {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let CustomLoginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerID") as! customVC

        let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: CustomLoginVC)
        navVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin]

        navVC.navigationBar.translucent = false
        navVC.navigationItem.title = "haha"
        navVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navVC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 22)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor() ]
        navVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 18)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonPressedInPDF")
        let exportButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named: "export"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "saveAsPDF")

        navVC.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, animated: false)
        navVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(exportButton, animated: false)
        window.rootViewController = navVC
        self.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

As you can see I'm instantiating `CustomLoginVC` which is a type of `customVC` from Main storyboard. `customVC` is a subclass of UIViewController. Then, initialize UINavigationController with `CustomLoginVC` and assign left and right bar button items. However, title and bar button items are not shown on the nav bar like below image.

[image]

I'm not understanding why bar button items and title are not made on the nav bar.

Also in `AppDelegate`, I set the method like following:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: "00BFA5")
        application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

        return true
    }
```

Any comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the title and buttons on `CustomLoginVC` and not on `navVC`

Comment: it worked when I did as you told me. But I don't get why I need to set the title and buttons on CustomLoginVC but not on navVC. Don't I need to set the buttons and title on UINavigationController?  CustomLoginVC is not UINavigationController but UIViewController

Comment: We always set buttons and title on the associated viewcontroller of navigation controller. And even the action methods for corresponding barbuttons are written in viewcontroller and not in navigation controller. Navigation controller is just a holder of viewcontrollers where one can push and pop

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write to below three line try it:

```
    navVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    navVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    navVC.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
```

after that try to write:

```
navVC.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, animated: false)
navVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(exportButton, animated: false)
```

OR

```
self.title = "Your Title"

var homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

var logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RigthButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
```